# Saving huge model object to file

Tags: r

Say you have a model object of class 'varrest' returned from a VAR() regression operation.
I want to save the model to a file, but not all data which was used to estimate the coefficients.

How can one just save the model specification wihtout the training data?
Because when I save the model it has a file size of over 1GB and therefore loading does take its time.
Can one save objects without some attributes?

Comment: You should specify the packages/functions you are using to create an object of class `varrest`

Comment: package is 'vars' and function is 'VAR'

Comment: How do you want to perform the prediction based on the estimated model? Do you do it "by hand" using only the model coefficients, or do you use something like the `prediction` method?

Comment: I'd like to use the 'prediction' method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The predict.varest function starts out with this code:

```
K <- object$K
p <- object$p
obs <- object$obs
type <- object$type
data.all <- object$datamat
ynames <- colnames(object$y)
```

You can then investigate how much pruning you might achieve:

```
data(Canada)
tcan <- 
VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "trend")
names(tcan)
# [1] "varresult"    "datamat"      "y"            "type"         "p"           
# [6] "K"            "obs"          "totobs"       "restrictions" "call"        
 object.size(tcan[c("K","p", "obs", "type", "datamat", "y")] )
#15080 bytes
 object.size(tcan)
#252032 bytes
```

So the difference is substantial, but just saving those items is not sufficient because the next line in predict.varest is:

```
B <- Bcoef(object)
```

You will need to add that object to the list above and then construct a new predict-function that accepts something less than the large 'varresult' node of the model object. Also turned out that there was a downstream call to an internal function that needs to be stored. (You will need to decide in advance what interval you need for prediction.)

```
tsmall <- c( tcan[c("K","p", "obs", "type", "datamat", "y", "call")] )
tsmall[["Bco"]] <- Bcoef(tcan)
tsmall$sig.y <- vars:::.fecov(x = tcan, n.ahead = 10)
```

And the modified `predict` function will be:

```
sm.predict <- function (object, ..., n.ahead = 10, ci = 0.95, dumvar = NULL) 
{
    K <- object$K
    p <- object$p
    obs <- object$obs
    type <- object$type
    data.all <- object$datamat
    ynames <- colnames(object$y)
    n.ahead <- as.integer(n.ahead)
    Z <- object$datamat[, -c(1:K)]
  # This used to be a call to Bcoef(object)
    B <- object$Bco
    if (type == "const") {
        Zdet <- matrix(rep(1, n.ahead), nrow = n.ahead, ncol = 1)
        colnames(Zdet) <- "const"
    }
    else if (type == "trend") {
        trdstart <- nrow(Z) + 1 + p
        Zdet <- matrix(seq(trdstart, length = n.ahead), nrow = n.ahead, 
            ncol = 1)
        colnames(Zdet) <- "trend"
    }
    else if (type == "both") {
        trdstart <- nrow(Z) + 1 + p
        Zdet <- matrix(c(rep(1, n.ahead), seq(trdstart, length = n.ahead)), 
            nrow = n.ahead, ncol = 2)
        colnames(Zdet) <- c("const", "trend")
    }
    else if (type == "none") {
        Zdet <- NULL
    }
    if (!is.null(eval(object$call$season))) {
        season <- eval(object$call$season)
        seas.names <- paste("sd", 1:(season - 1), sep = "")
        cycle <- tail(data.all[, seas.names], season)
        seasonal <- as.matrix(cycle, nrow = season, ncol = season - 
            1)
        if (nrow(seasonal) >= n.ahead) {
            seasonal <- as.matrix(cycle[1:n.ahead, ], nrow = n.ahead, 
                ncol = season - 1)
        }
        else {
            while (nrow(seasonal) < n.ahead) {
                seasonal <- rbind(seasonal, cycle)
            }
            seasonal <- seasonal[1:n.ahead, ]
        }
        rownames(seasonal) <- seq(nrow(data.all) + 1, length = n.ahead)
        if (!is.null(Zdet)) {
            Zdet <- as.matrix(cbind(Zdet, seasonal))
        }
        else {
            Zdet <- as.matrix(seasonal)
        }
    }
    if (!is.null(eval(object$call$exogen))) {
        if (is.null(dumvar)) {
            stop("\nNo matrix for dumvar supplied, but object varest contains exogenous variables.\n")
        }
        if (!all(colnames(dumvar) %in% colnames(data.all))) {
            stop("\nColumn names of dumvar do not coincide with exogen.\n")
        }
        if (!identical(nrow(dumvar), n.ahead)) {
            stop("\nRow number of dumvar is unequal to n.ahead.\n")
        }
        if (!is.null(Zdet)) {
            Zdet <- as.matrix(cbind(Zdet, dumvar))
        }
        else {
            Zdet <- as.matrix(dumvar)
        }
    }
    Zy <- as.matrix(object$datamat[, 1:(K * (p + 1))])
    yse <- matrix(NA, nrow = n.ahead, ncol = K)
  # This used to be a call to vars:::.fecov
    sig.y <- object$sig.y
    for (i in 1:n.ahead) {
        yse[i, ] <- sqrt(diag(sig.y[, , i]))
    }
    yse <- -1 * qnorm((1 - ci)/2) * yse
    colnames(yse) <- paste(ci, "of", ynames)
    forecast <- matrix(NA, ncol = K, nrow = n.ahead)
    lasty <- c(Zy[nrow(Zy), ])
    for (i in 1:n.ahead) {
        lasty <- lasty[1:(K * p)]; print(lasty); print(B)
        Z <- c(lasty, Zdet[i, ]) ;print(Z)
        forecast[i, ] <- B %*% Z
        temp <- forecast[i, ]
        lasty <- c(temp, lasty)
    }
    colnames(forecast) <- paste(ynames, ".fcst", sep = "")
    lower <- forecast - yse
    colnames(lower) <- paste(ynames, ".lower", sep = "")
    upper <- forecast + yse
    colnames(upper) <- paste(ynames, ".upper", sep = "")
    forecasts <- list()
    for (i in 1:K) {
        forecasts[[i]] <- cbind(forecast[, i], lower[, i], upper[, 
            i], yse[, i])
        colnames(forecasts[[i]]) <- c("fcst", "lower", "upper", 
            "CI")
    }
    names(forecasts) <- ynames
    result <- list(fcst = forecasts, endog = object$y, model = object, 
        exo.fcst = dumvar)
    class(result) <- "varprd"
    return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Either

- set the attributes you do not want to NULL, or
- copy the parts you want to a new object, or
- call the `save()` function with proper indexing.

Comment: I think the main issue here is to find out which parts of the model are needed by `predict`. If the prediction was made "by hand", _i.e._ by multiplication with the coefficient matrix, only the coefficients of an estimated model `x` would be needed, which can simply be obtained by `do.call(rbind, lapply(x$varresult, coef))`