# How to strip down the glm model?

Tags: r, glm

The object returned by [`glm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html) contains `residuals`, `fitted values`, `effects`, `qr$qr`, `linear.predictors`, `weights` &c &c which add up to a humongous object (if the input is big enough).

How do I strip it down so that *something like* `predict` will still work?

Ideally, I want a function which would return a *small* function object equivalent to `function(x) predict(my_model,data.frame(x=x))`; something like [`as.stepfun`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/stepfun.html) for [`isoreg`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/isoreg.html).

Comment: http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/reducing-your-r-memory-footprint-by-7000x.html This might help

Comment: I remembered answering a similar question but it turned out to be for a different regression function. You still might find it useful because I described the process (and I know you are not afraid of hacking): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011005/saving-huge-model-object-to-file/14015021?s=6|0.1706#14015021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the model components are descriptive, and are not necessary for `predict` to work. A helper function ([HT: R-Bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/trimming-the-fat-from-glm-models-in-r/)) can be used to remove the fat:

```
stripGlmLR = function(cm) {
  cm$y = c()
  cm$model = c()

  cm$residuals = c()
  cm$fitted.values = c()
  cm$effects = c()
  cm$qr$qr = c()  
  cm$linear.predictors = c()
  cm$weights = c()
  cm$prior.weights = c()
  cm$data = c()


  cm$family$variance = c()
  cm$family$dev.resids = c()
  cm$family$aic = c()
  cm$family$validmu = c()
  cm$family$simulate = c()
  attr(cm$terms,".Environment") = c()
  attr(cm$formula,".Environment") = c()

  cm
}
```

Now you can apply it to your model for a 5+ order-of-magnitude reduction in size (in this example):

```
traindata <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1e6), y = rnorm(1e6))
testdata <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10))

mod1 <- glm(y~x, data= traindata)
mod2 <- stripGlmLR(mod1)

format(object.size(mod1), units = "Kb")
# [1] "492234.5 Kb"
format(object.size(mod2), units = "Kb")
# [1] "18.5 Kb"

all(predict(object = mod1, newdata = testdata) == 
    predict(object = mod2, newdata = testdata))
# [1] TRUE
```

Note that if you want to be able to use the full suite of `glm` methods, you will need to retain other components of the model.