# kernlab ksvm returned models are huge, any way to trim training data to reduce size?

Tags: r

I use `kernlab`/`ksvm` with the vanilladot kernel. The resulting models appear to contain training data, which makes them huge. In particular there is a slot named `xmatrix`, which is 150+ MB. It seems that the original training data is not necessary once the model has been created, but if I get rid of it prediction does not work anymore. Can anyone think of a way of at least trimming its size or some other way of solving the problem?

Comment: I've never examined the internals of the prediction methods for that class of models. As an example of how to reduce the size of a model object so that a smaller data component might be used (albeit with  different class) you might look at the SO answer I provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011005/saving-huge-model-object-to-file/14015021?s=13|0.4795#14015021 , To support further attention to you question you might provide the code needed to create a minimal example (obviously not using your 150+MB data).

Comment: `code`# This code works, the xmatrix is there. Of course it is quite small in this case, 
# but in real life it is huge.
library(kernlab)
myRows=10;myCols=5
myMat<-matrix(runif(myCols*myRows), ncol=myCols)
colnames(myMat)=paste("V",1:myCols,sep="")
m=ksvm(V1~.,myMat,kernel="vanilladot")
pr=predict(m, myMat[,2:myCols])
# if I try replacing it with something, like this dummy one row matrix,
# it breaks predicting
m@xmatrix=matrix(nrow=1,ncol=myCols)
Error in .local(object, ...) : test vector does not match model !

Comment: Makes no sense to post such code in a comment. Choose the `edit` button above and improve your question where you will be able to properly format. You should also read the help page for the predict method for this class of object. Such methods differ in the needed arguments.